# Sphinx Error: 'unknown local index 'message' in search request'

Tags: php, sphinx

```
source tasks : common
{
  sql_query = \
    SELECT \
        t.tasks_id, \
        t.tasks_id AS task_id, \
        t.message AS message \
    FROM \
        tasks AS t \

  sql_field_string = task_id
  sql_field_string = message
}
```

Use php method

```
$sphinx->Query('добро', 'message');
```

[Manual method Query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.query.php)

As far as I know, sql_field_ * creates an index and a field. So why does it give an error when query?

But if I use '*' all worked, but I want, when searched at message field

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, sql_field_ * creates an index and a field. So why does it give an error when query?

No. sql_field_ creates a field **in** an existing index. Not a whole new index.

So the index based on this source, will have the message field. Persuambly you have
something like

```
index tasks {
   source = tasks
   ...
}
```

In which case can use the field syntax to search the specific field

```
$sphinx->Query('@message добро', 'tasks');
```

(it's best to search the *specific* `tasks` index, rather than all indexes (with `*`) as the query would only work on indexes that DO have a `message` field)